# What is the .~lock. prefix for a file?

Tags: files

I have a directory of notes on my system.
When I enter `ls -A`, I see my regular files, plus some files prefixed with `.~lock.` and ended with #

For instance,

`ls -A` gives:

```
Compiling.odt      .~lock.Compiling.odt#
Environment.odt    .~lock.Scripting.odt#
```

What are these files and what is their purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a libreoffice / openoffice - specific file meant to tell other LO/OO instances that the file is opened in one instance.

From [ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/51950/lockfilenameodt/)

> @peterwt:
>   The lock file is created when a document is opened and normally deleted when the document is closed. It's purpose is in a multi user environment to prevent more than one user to edit a document, which would create a problem. The first user to open the file will be able to edit the document but any subsequent users who open the document will be in read only mode.